# Sobel filter is working on the original i/p image but not on the copy of it

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to apply Sobel and other filter at an image but i can see the results of filter only if i use the filters at original input image. But if i implement the filter at a copy of inout image then nothing happens and just a white output image appears.

In the following code i am implementing the filter at original `inputImage` but i want to get results by implementing it at `copyImage`.

```
inputImage=imread('tex.png');
copyImage=double(inputImage);

for i=1:size(C,1)-2
    for j=1:size(C,2)-2
        %Sobel mask for x-direction:
        Gx=((2*C(i+2,j+1)+C(i+2,j)+C(i+2,j+2))-(2*C(i,j+1)+C(i,j)+C(i,j+2)));
        %Sobel mask for y-direction:
        Gy=((2*C(i+1,j+2)+C(i,j+2)+C(i+2,j+2))-(2*C(i+1,j)+C(i,j)+C(i+2,j)));

        %The gradient of the image
        inputImage(i,j)=sqrt(Gx.^2+Gy.^2);
    end
end
```

Comment: Remove the `double` from copyImage, and then replace `inputImage` in the for loop with `copyImage`.

Answer (score 4):

`imshow` with a `double` argument expects the values to be in the range 0.0 (black) to 1.0 (white). Anything greater than 1 is clipped to white. Since presumably `inputImage` is integer, using `double(inputImage)` doesn't rescale and you end up with `double` values in ranges like 0-255 or 0-65535 depending on the bit depth, which therefore just show as white.

If you need `double` format, use `im2double` which rescales the values correctly. Otherwise, just create an integer copy with `copyImage = inputImage`.

If you don't have the Image Processing Toolbox for `im2double`, you can do an unsigned integer-to-double image conversion with:

```
dblimg = double(img) ./ double(intmax(class(img)));
```